# Add image element to an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, image

I would like to add an image inside of a dynamically created link element using Javascript.  Here is my code:

```
a.textContent = "My Link";
a.setAttribute('href', "#");
```

I would like the image to appear before the text in the link (My Link). In HTML, the resulting link would be:

```
<a href="#"><img src="foo.gif">My Link</a>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) with `afterbegin`,

```
a.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<img src='foo.gif'>")
```

The above code will *prepend* the `image` element supplied as a html string into the target anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="testImage"></a>
$('#testImage').html('<img src="foo.gif">My Link');
```

Use this